# Ceiling Drywall Direction

Tags: drywall, ceiling

I plan on installing 1/2" lightweight drywall over an existing textured ceiling. The room measures 23' x 8.5'. Joists run parallel to the short end of the room, spaced 16" however there is another single joist that runs parallel to the long end of the run (see attached picture but make note I didnt include all the 16" joists so that it looks cleaner).

Do you recommend I buy 4x10 sheets and run them parallel to the joists to minimize joints? I'm just afraid of the joists not being absolutely accurate and then it turning into a hassle.

Or should I just run them perpendicular and then have a 6" leftover piece at the ends since the room is 8.5'?

Thanks in advance for any help.[image: Room Layout]

Comment: You're right that running parallel is more likely to result in hassle. Straight and square for that length is unlikely. Drywall is cheap.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. If an answer is helpful, please click the large check mark next to it to accept. And, please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Watch this video...it's less than 2 minutes:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fut-vSG32jY

Answer (score 2):

Go for the easiest option.  It isn't worth trying to maximize material usage or trying to get a few less seams.

Even 1/2" drywall sheets are heavy.  I'd opt for 4x8 especially if you aren't renting a drywall lift.  Even if you are using a lift you still have to move the sheets around.  A couple more tape seems just isn't a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

This question might be opinion based. I would buy the 4x10 sheets and run them parallel to the studs. You can cut them at the home store to the 8.5' length and installing them won't be much more difficult or heavier than the 4x8 pieces. Your seems will all have the finished edge, except one, which does make it easier to tape and minimizing overhead seams is always a good idea. Play it safe and rent a drywall lift.